# SQL Server Replication to Archive DB

Tags: sql-server, replication, archive

I maintain a SQL Server 2017 database server with production (PROD) and reporting (REPORT) databases.  The databases have similar structure, but the time span of the production database is 3 years and the archive database contains all data since the beginning of the system delivery.

We want to set up replication from PROD to REPORT so that any new changes to PROD get replicated to REPORT.  However, when my colleague set up replication, the REPORT db gets truncated and rebuilt so that it becomes a copy of PROD.  Are there any configuration that we are missing to maintain REPORT so that it contains all data including the updates?

Comment: What specific operation is truncating tables in your reporting (i.e. replication subscriber) db? Is it a replication of a truncation command at the publisher? Replication of delete commands? Application of a replication snapshot?

Comment: I believe it was initially set up as unidirectional merge replication and it was set up as bi-directional (by mistake)